# How to remove line duplicates SQL via compare two same table

Tags: sql, duplicates, compare, row

How to remove duplicate values a = b and b = a?

```
with a as(select w.id , w.doc, w.org 
, d.name_s, d.name_f, d.name_p, d.spec      
, o.name, o.extid    
from crm_s_workplaces w    
join crm_s_docs d on d.id=w.doc    
join crm_s_orgs o on o.id=w.org    
where d.active=1 and d.cst='NY' and w.active=1 and w.cst='NY' and o.active=1 
and    
o.cst='NY')     
select a1.doc, a2.doc,    
a1.org,a1.name_s,a1.name_f,a1.name_p,a2.name_s,a2.name_f,a2.name_p from a a1    
join a a2 on     
a1.name_s=a2.name_s and    
substr(a1.name_f,1,1)=substr(a2.name_f,1,1) and    
substr(a1.name_p,1,1)=substr(a2.name_p,1,1) and     
a1.org=a2.org and    
a1.spec<>a2.spec    
order by a1.name_s    `enter code here`
```

ER model diagram:

[image: ermodel-diagram]

Repeat example:

[image: repeat example]

Sometimes comes across `a1.spec > a2.spec`:

[image: sometimes comes across a1.spec>a2.spec]

Comment: Left justified SQL is hard to read. Properly formatted SQL is easier to read and also to write!

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling "duplicates" are actually not duplicates in your database.

You basically have multiple doc records for what could be the same person or not. See that even their names do not always match. For instace,

doc_id 1131385 has NAME_F = "Gabr" while 
doc_id 1447530 has NAME_F = "Gabor"

In your database these are two different entities, and you cannot match them using primary key. You can try to join on the first, middle and last names, but as you can see in the above example with Gabor/Gabr, even that would not work.

Can you change the schema of the db? If so you need to separate the docs in one table - 1 record per doctor. And have the specialization in a separate table with the folloing columns:

spec_id (int, PK)
doc_id (foreign key to Doc table)
specialization

that way, if you have 1 doctor with 3 specs, he/she will show up only once in doc table, and multiple times in spec table.

I just notice something else. You have spec field in table workplaces. why? If you meant to say that Doc Gabor works as admin in hospital 1 but as a Therapist in hospital 2, you can do that. However, you have to remove the spec field from the doc table and only use the spec in workplaces table.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qcVS.png sometimes come across the same records

Comment: I guess I need to know more about the a table and the spec field:What is the PK of table a? Is it correct that the same person may be presented in multiple records and may have different spec values?